# Find n from a random number rounded up to nearest triangle number

Tags: linear-algebra

Perhaps the questions is a little convoluted, what I'm looking for a concise method of finding the 'row' index where a random integer appears in a distribution like so:

```
1. *
2. **
3. ***
4. ****
5. *****
6. ******
7. *******
8. ********
```

Where if random number = x, you count x stars from the top-down, so:

if x = 5, row = 3;
if x = 1, row = 1;
if x = 25, row = 7;

So that a weighted random result is generated, with result 1 being the rarest, and 8 being the most common.

What I've tried:

I've found that n(n - 1) / 2 = T (triangle number). I feel like this is key, but I'm not sure how to solve for n if given a triangle number, my algebra is failing me. Finally, if I'm able to find n from a triangle number, then I'll need a way of taking my random number and rounding up to the nearest triangle number.

Or perhaps there's a simpler way, I suspect I'm torturing it. Please let me know if I'm on the right track, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting that the question you're asking is:
Given an integer $n$, find the smallest integer $r$ so that the sum $1+2+3+ \dots r$ is larger than or equal to $n$. 
The sum is equal to
$$
1 + 2+ 3 \dots + r = \sum_{k=1}^r k = \frac{1}{2}r(r+1)
$$
Therefore, we want
$$
\frac{1}{2}r(r+1) \geq n \Rightarrow r^2 +r -2n \geq 0
$$
The solution to $r^2 +r -2n = 0$ is $r= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{8n+1} \right)$. We should choose the positive value $r= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sqrt{8n+1} \right).$ Taking the floor function of this works everywhere else than on the boundaries (end of the row), so we can subtract one from $n$ in order to make it correct. The answer is
$$
r = \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sqrt{8(n-1) + 1} \right) \right\rfloor
$$

Comment: Your idea is the right one (+1). I edited my answer to give perhaps a slight improvement (no edge cases).

Comment: Great, thank you, i appreciate you really breaking it down, this is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

For a given positive integer $x$, let $n$ be the corresponding row.

Let $T_n =  {\large{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$ be the $n$-th triangular number.

Then the last element in the $n$-th row is $T_n$.

Thus, since $x$ is in the $n$-th row, we must have $T_{n-1} < x \le T_n\\[8pt]$
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&T_{n-1} < x \le T_n\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{(n-1)n}{2} < x \le \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{n^2-n}{2} < x \le \frac{n^2+n}{2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4n^2-4n < 8x \le 4n^2+4n\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4n^2-4n + 1 < 8x+1 \le 4n^2+4n+1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2n-1)^2 < 8x+1 \le (2n+1)^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2n-1 < \sqrt{8x+1} \le 2n+1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Letting $y ={\Large{\lceil}}\!{\sqrt{8x+1}}\,{\Large{\rceil}}$, it follows that
$$
y=
\begin{cases}
2n  & \text{if $y$ is even}\\
2n+1 & \text{if $y$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Solving for $n$, we get
$$
n=
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{y}{2}}}  & \text{if $y$ is even}\\[4pt]
{\large{\frac{y-1}{2}}} & \text{if $y$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Hence in both cases, $n=\left\lfloor{{\large{\frac{y}{2}}}}\right\rfloor$.

Expressed in terms of $x$, we get
$$n=\left\lfloor{
\frac
{
{\Large{\lceil}}\!{\sqrt{8x+1}}\,{\Large{\rceil}}
}
{2}
}
\right\rfloor
$$

Edit:

Matti P.'s solution is simpler than mine.

With a minor tweak, it can be made simpler still . . .

Noting that the function
$$f(t) = \frac{t(t+1)}{2}$$
is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, if we take the nonnegative solution of the equaton $f(t) = x$, all we need to do is round up (i.e., take the ceiling).

This yields
$$n=\left\lceil{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{8x+1}}{2}}\right\rceil$$
which is equivalent both to Matti P.'s result and to my previous result.

But let me point out that for my previous result 
$$n=\left\lfloor{
\frac
{
{\Large{\lceil}}\!{\sqrt{8x+1}}\,{\Large{\rceil}}
}
{2}
}
\right\rfloor
$$
the square root is eliminated right away (by taking the ceiling), so in that sense, even though the formula involves taking both a ceiling and a floor, the calculation is simpler.